# SPARQL - Looking for all properties from particular namespace

Tags: regex, sparql

I am trying to determine the set of unique properties used in our DB from a particular namespace. For example, if I want to see all the properties we use from the Dublin Core set, I'm trying:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
SELECT DISTINCT
    ?pred   
WHERE 
    { 
    ?sub ?pred ?obj  . 
    FILTER regex(?pred, "purl.org/dc/elements") 
    } 
limit 1000
```

I'm looking at all triples, filtering via regex for just triples with the DC namespace, and then returning a list of distinct predicates. This query times out when I run it, so I'm unsure if that's because of the volume being checked, or if the query itself is faulty.
What I really want is a list of predicates that start with the DC namespace.

Comment: Example on Wikidata: https://w.wiki/LoP

Comment: the query is fine, it's just that it has to scan the whole dataset and do an expensive `regex` operation on each triple predicate. What @StanislavKralin did is a nice optimization that humans are able to do because we know that actually we just need to do it for all "distinct predicate only" and not "for all triples", therefore the subquery to get all `?p` and then only perform on those (usually less) values the `regex`. Moreover, using `strstarts` is likely to be more efficient in many programming languages compared to the more powerful but unnecessary `regex`.

Answer (score 2):

```
FILTER( STRSTARTS(str(?pred), str(dc:)) )
```

This does two things:

1. Turn URIs into strings with `str`because `STRSTARTS` (and `REGEX`) work on strings.
2. Use `dc:` as a short hand for the URL for the predicates. The parser will expand it to the full `http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/`

Comment: Just a note that it is `STRSTARTS` and NOT `STRSTART` (as in code example).